# Understanding "nvidia-smi topo -m" output

Tags: cuda, gpu, mpi, pci-e, multi-gpu

In order to leverage the GPUs on a system, I'd like to be able to draw a block diagram and understand the connections represented by "nvidia-smi topo -m" output.

Here is an example output:
[image]

[image]

Can someone provide a system level block diagram of this?  Descriptions of the connections would be great too.  I'm sure this would help many people exploit their multi gpu systems.

Comment: what is this node? does not look like DGX1.

Comment: have you tried the `lstopo` command from the `hwloc` package ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet good idea, I have not even thought about using tools from MPI side.

Comment: note that even if the `hwloc` project is hosted by the Open MPI project, this is a standalone package that is independent from the MPI library. note you might have to build `hwloc` by yourself and configure it with `--with-cuda`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet how do I check if hwloc is compiled with CUDA support? So I cannot depend on the hwloc installed by the package manager?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have two CPU sockets. Each CPU has a PCIe host bridge (PHB) leading to two PCIe switches. Each of the (two times two) PCIe switches has two GPUs connected to it, for a total of eight.
[image]

Comment: Actually I liked a lot the pictures in this arxiv paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.04611.pdf

Comment: Awesome!  I think this will help a bunch of people.  It would be amazing if nvidia built this into nvidia-smi,

Comment: Are there any good resources to help me understand why PHB may be slower than PIX? Is the CPU itself involved in the critical path of copying data? Are system RAM pages used as bounce buffers?